# Trigger tooltip manually in React-Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, react-bootstrap

How can I trigger [Tooltip](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/tooltips/#tooltips) manually in React-Bootstrap?

I tried this code, but tooltip doesn't show:

```
const tooltip = (
      <Tooltip id="tooltip">
        <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> Check this info.
      </Tooltip>
    );

<OverlayTrigger placement="left" overlay={tooltip} trigger="manual" show>
      <input />
</OverlayTrigger>
```

I want to achieve this:

```
$('.popover').popover({
        trigger: 'manual',
        html: true,
        content() {
          return error.message;
        },
      });
$('.popover').popover('show');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can play with `show` prop available for Tooltip.

```
const show = false;
const tooltip = (
      <Tooltip id="tooltip" show={show}>
        <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> Check this info.
      </Tooltip>
    );
```